# Why am I getting a "network is unreachable" error on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, internet-connection

I'm a completely new to Ubuntu server and am having a hard time connecting the server to the internet.

I first ran ping -n 8.8.8.8

```
connect:Network is unreachable
```

Then I ran ifconfig

```
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask 255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/28Scope:host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436
RX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:15360 (15.2KB) TX bytes:15360 (15.3KB)
```

Here is ouput for sudo lspci -n

```
00:00.0 0600: 8086:2580 (rev 04)
00:02.0 0300: 8086:2582 (rev 04)
00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:2658 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 0c03: 8086:2659 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:265a (rev 03)
00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:265b (rev 03)
00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:265c (rev 03)
00:1e.0 0604: 8086:244e (rev d3)
00:1e.0 0401: 8086:266e (rev 03)
00:1f.0 0601: 8086:2640 (rev 03)
00:1f.0 0101: 8086:2651 (rev 03)
00:1f.0 0c05: 8086:266a (rev 03)
00:0b.0 0200: 8086:1654 (rev 03)
```

lshw-c network returns

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-network DISABLED
description:Ethernet interface
product: NetXtreme BCM5705_2 Gigabit Ethernet
vender: Broadcom Corporation
physical id:b
bus info:pci@0000:0a:0b.0
logical name: eth0
capabilities: bus_master_cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 

1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion= 3.121 

firmware=5705-v3.18 latency=32 mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twister pair
```

lsmod code returned this

```
Module              Size          Used By
e100                37213           0
dm_crypt            23125           1
ppdev               17113           0
psmouse             87603           0
snd_intel8x0        38570           0
snd_ac97_codec      134826          1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus            12730           1  snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm             97188           2 snd_intel8x0, snd_ac97_codec
serio_raw           13211           0
snd_timer           29990           1  snd_pcm
snd                 78855           4 snd_intel8x0, snd_ac97_codec, snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore           15091           1 snd
snd_page_alloc      18529           2  snd_intel8x0, snd_pcm
ext2                73795           1
parport_pc          32866           1
mac_hid             13253           0
lp                  17799           0
parport             46562           3    ppdev, parport_pc,lp
usbhid              47199           0
hid                 99559           1 usbhid
tg3                 152032          0
i915                468651          1
floppy              70365           0
drm_kms_helper      46978           1 i915
drm                 242038 2 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit        13423 1 i915
video               19596 1 i915
```

Again there is more but it's giving info on the driver itself. I know it works, I've used it. I assume then that my network got disabled when I installed Ubuntu Server. How do I enable it?

I checked and the internet cable is connected to the D-link router. I have also used this same computer for internet access when I had Ubuntu Desktop installed so internet does work.

Comment: Unless there's more in the "trivial" stuff you've omitted, `ifconfig` appears to show that Ubuntu is detecting no ethernet/wireless/network card (interface) that will let you connect to the outside world (`loopback` is an internal interface). I think that's the first hurdle you need to clear -- can you edit the question with details of your motherboard/laptop model and possibly pastebin the output of `sudo lspci -nn` and `sudo lshw -c network`?

Comment: If anyoe is unsure who operates `8.8.8.8`, it is Google Public (recursive) DBS for IPv4, along with `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: pastebin output of `lsmod`, please -- these closed-source BCM ethernet chips are a b-, sorry...

Comment: You could try `modprobe tg3`  and you might need the package `firmware-linux-nonfree`

Comment: I had similar symptoms after plugging in a router in my pppoe connection. Turned out silly - I had cloned the computer's address to set it to the routers (ISP's MAC filtering) and the two devices had identical MAC-s. As I said - silly.

Answer (score 1):

As you see from the hardware list, this is a `NetXtreme BCM5705_2 Gigabit Ethernet` device which needs the Linux driver `tg3` and firmware to work.  The firmware are not free, so you need to install the package `firmware-linux-nonfree` to make it work.

- Start looking at the logs with `sudo tail -f /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog` in
  one new terminal. Here you can see what happens with the other commands.  Look for lines with `tg3` or `firmware`.
- Install the firmware package.  You need to add `multiverse` (nonfree in Debian) in `/etc/atp/sources.list` after the word `universe`, like `universe multiverse`.
- After you have saved the changes, do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`.  Look in the manual for more information: `man sources.list`.
- Run `sudo modprobe -r tg3` to unload the driver and then `sudo modprobe tg3` to load the driver to see if the propper firmware get loaded.  Look at the log you started to look at earlier with the `tail`-command to see what happens. It should show up there that the devices is installed and that the firmware is installed.
- If it works, set up the network in `/etc/network/interfaces` and execute `sudo ifup eth1` or what your device name are.

In short, you don't have the firmware that is needed to operate your network card.  The firmware for this card should be in the package `firmware-linux-nonfree` in section `multiverse`.

Good luck with the computer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know if this changes things but I put in the code sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 and now it shows the network is working. Does this change anything?

Comment: Also, I'm getting several errors from your code instructions. sudo tail -f /var/log/messages returns saying No such file or directory. dpkg -i *.deb also says that No such file or directory. It also says Errors were encountered while proecessing: *.deb.

Comment: You should be able to manage misspellings in answers and examples. ;)  Do you have a file /var/log/messages?  You should prefer to install the package through your repository, the deb package is last resort. Have you downloaded the package?